# Styling Dialogs with Java 8 Update 25 and openjfx-dialogs

Tags: javafx

I've been using the latest Java 8 Update 40 Early Access and its dialogs.. however, now I'm switching to Java 8 Update 25 and openjfx-dialogs 1.02 instead, due to the fact that Update 40 isn't available until March of 2015.

With Update 40, I was able to easily style the dialogs with this code:

```
dlg.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add("mystylesheet.css");
```

However, with Update 25 and openjfx-dialogs, the Dialogs won't get styled.

I have "dialog-pane" set in mystylesheet.css, and by the looks of it (from the source-code), it should be correctly named... however, for some reason the style is not applied..?

Answer (score 0):

I 'fixed' this by renaming ".dialog-pane" to "#dialog-pane", and setting the ID for DialogPane via setId().